# Troubles with getting case class fields via reflection

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, scala-reflect

I have a scala code: trait model and its implementation case class Category with custom annotation which i wish to read later

```scala
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
class ExtraFields() extends StaticAnnotation

trait Model {}

case class MyCategory( id: Option[Int],
                     name: String,
                     level: Option[Int],

                     @ExtraFields
                     parent: Option[MyCategory] = None
                   ) extends Model {

}
```

and i have trait DBModel and its implementation MyCategoryModel. And i pass MyCategory as type parameter to DBModel

```scala
trait DBModel[T <: Model] {
  lazy val fields = getClassFields[T]
  lazy val fields2 = getClassFields2[T]
}

object MyCategoryModel extends DBModel[MyCategory] {
  def getFields = fields
  def getFields2 = fields2
}
```

i want trait DBModel to read fields of case class passed as T parameter, so i call two functions

```scala
def getClassFields[T] = {
  symbolOf[T].asClass.primaryConstructor
    .typeSignature.paramLists.head.map {v =>
      v.name.toString -> v.annotations
    }
}

def getClassFields2[T: TypeTag]: Iterable[(String, List[universe.Annotation])] =
  typeOf[T].members.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor =>
      m.name.toString -> m.annotations
  }
```

but none of them is working

```scala
val res = MyCategoryModel.getFields // runtime exception: free type T is not a class
val res2 = MyCategoryModel.getFields2 // compile error: No TypeTag available for T
```

If i call them directly

```scala
getClassFields[MyCategory]
getClassFields2[MyCategory]
```

for a first function i get the same error, for the second i get result but universe.annotations can not see my ExtraFields annotation, returning empty lists for each of fields

Could you please explain this black magic and how to conqure it in my case
Thank you

UPD playground https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DTTTyA0CSTSZ0Vj7KFW6Hw

Comment: You can find annotations at compile time `shapeless.Annotations[ExtraFields, MyCategory].apply()`. This produces `None :: None :: None :: Some(ExtraFields@4f5991f6) :: HNil`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin, that's even more convinient for me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing type class `WeakTypeTag` for `getClassFields`.

Additionally, you're not passing the type classes in a trait `DBModel[T <: Model]`.

One solution is to define them as context bounds of type `T`. But for this to work, it is required to pass these type classes via a constructor. And because traits do not have constructors, the solution is to use `abstract class`.

So the following fixes the compilation problems

```scala
abstract class DBModel[T <: Model : WeakTypeTag : TypeTag] {
  lazy val fields = getClassFields[T]
  lazy val fields2 = getClassFields2[T]
}

def getClassFields[T: WeakTypeTag] = ???
def getClassFields2[T: TypeTag] = ???
```

The method `getClassFields2` is not finding annotations because of the way annotations are specified. If defined as following, both methods work. For more info read [meta docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/meta/index.html)

```scala
  
import scala.annotation.meta.{getter, param}
case class MyCategory(
     id: Option[Int],
     name: String,
     level: Option[Int],
     @(ExtraFields @param @getter) parent: Option[MyCategory] = None
  ) extends Model
```

Comment: Could you please explain  `@(ExtraFields @param @getter) parent: Option[MyCategory] = None`` or give a link with explanation about @param and @getter. In playground this line throws error https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kJ8rlP98SaOBSzA5Ap4oIA

Comment: @DmitryReutov Please read [mets docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/meta/index.html)

Comment: @DmitryReutov you're missing imports `import scala.annotation.meta.{getter, param}`

Comment: @IvanStanislavovich, ok! i got